# update data if object id matches otherwise create a new object in mongodb mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my **userSchema**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { cartSchema } from "./cart";
const { ObjectId } = mongoose;
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      min: 6,
      max: 64,
      required: true,
    },
    dob: {
      type: Date,
    },
    gender: {
      type: String,
    },
    seller: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    shop_id: {
      type: ObjectId,
    },
    cart: {
      type: [cartSchema]
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

and this is my **cartSchema**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { ObjectId } = mongoose;
const { Schema } = mongoose;

export const cartSchema = new Schema({
  item_id: {
    type: String,
  },
  qty: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

Now, the cart schema is basically used to store my shopping cart orders, and I'm trying to implement it in such a way that, if the item_id has already been added, qty increases by 1. Otherwise, a new cart object is added to the array and its qty should be set to 1.

How do i write mongoose code for the same? Please help me.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't perform such action with one query (for updating qty by 1). If it's OK for you to have 2 queries, I can try to provide an example.

Comment: okay please help me out

Comment: Hmm, one thing. How do you know which document/cart you should check? By _id or something else?